# BoundaryPatch in Android SDK

Tags: android, android-browser

I have downloaded Browser application source from
git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git

And trying to compile it with eclipse ADT. I got an error that there is no:
***android.graphics.utils.BoundaryPatch***

I tried to use different branches froyo, gingerbread. But all they have this BoundaryPatch. Should I somehow patch android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot build the Browser with the Android SDK. You can only build the Browser as part of a full firmware build.